# disable previous dates in a jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to implement a jquery datepicker. I have two input text boxes datepicker1 and datepicker2. I am trying to disable the dates in the second input box based on the user date selection on the first input box. That means the dates behind the user selected date on the first input box should be disabled. Same for any date change
I have tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
<script>
  $(function(){

  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
     $.extend($.datepicker.regional['']) );

  //$('#datepicker').datepicker();


  var datepicker1=$('#datepicker1').datepicker({minDate: 'now'});
  //var datepicker2=$('#datepicker2').datepicker({minDate: 'now' + 1});
  var datepicker2=$('#datepicker2').datepicker
  (
    {minDate:($( ".datepicker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" ))+1}
  );
  //$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', $.datepicker.regional['fr']);



  });
</script>
```

the html file is:testjs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- add scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script>
$(function(){

  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
     $.extend($.datepicker.regional['']) );

  //$('#datepicker').datepicker();


  var datepicker1=$('#datepicker1').datepicker({minDate: 'now'});
  //var datepicker2=$('#datepicker2').datepicker({minDate: 'now' + 1});
  var datepicker2=$('#datepicker2').datepicker
  (
    {minDate:($( ".datepicker1" ).datepicker( "getDate" ))+1}
  );
  //$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', $.datepicker.regional['fr']);



  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>



<input id="datepicker1" type="text" />
<input id="datepicker2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give zero to mindate and it'll disabale past dates.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

here is a Live fiddle working example http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/ZL2Bc/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

For more info visit this link :https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

$(function () {
        $('.date_class').datetimepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dayOfWeekStart: 1,
            lang: 'en',
            startDate: 'date.now()',
            formatTime: 'g:i A',
            step: 30,
        });
    });